# Fabric.js Text field - issue with Android

Tags: android, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js and I have some problems with Text fields. They are apparently not editable on Android devices. I can select the Text area, but I cannot edit it.

This is my code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setHeight(500);
canvas.setWidth(500);
var canvasCenter = canvas.getCenter();

var title_input = new fabric.IText( dimensions.titleArgs['content'], {
    id: 'title',
    lineHeight: 1,
    fontStyle: 'normal',
    fontSize: 50,
    hasControls: false,
    lockMovementX: true,
    lockMovementY: true,
    centerTransform: true,
    top: canvasCenter["top"],
    left: canvasCenter["left"],
    originX: 'left',
    originY: 'bottom',
    fontFamily: "Helvetica Neue", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif'
});
canvas.add(title_input);

canvas.renderAll();
```

I am working with fabric v1.4.12 and I have made the tests on

- Samsung SM-T100 (Samsung Galaxy Tab 3), Android v. 4.2.2. and Chrome v. 38.0.212.102
- Samsung SM-G900F (Samsung Galaxy S5), Android v. 4.4.2. and Chrome v. 38.0.212.102

I have tested examples on fabricjs.com (http://fabricjs.com/test/misc/itext.html), where I had the same problem.

The applications works ok on iPad and on Desktop computer.

Is anyone else facing the same problem or would know how to solve it?

Comment: can you please provide some code how you are adding textfield?

Comment: @Innodel I have updated my question with some sample code.

Comment: looking at your code, everything is working fine, it looks like if you are having any other js in page than might have conflicting with that js to fabric. do one thing, make one JSFiddle, test on your devices and still if you face any problem than let me know with fiddle link

Comment: Here is a link to my JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/knospe/t4azmeyg/

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through your code and i have tested your code on my geonee phone after updation in you fiddle. Just make lockMovementX and lockMovementY to false. this will work on android and every where. Hope this helps

> http://jsfiddle.net/t4azmeyg/15/

```js
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

// Set canvas
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.selectionColor = 'rgba(255,0,0,1)';
canvas.selectionBorderColor = 'rgba(255,0,0,0.7)';
canvas.selectionLineWidth = 5;
canvas.backgroundColor = '#fff';
canvas.setHeight(500);
canvas.setWidth(500);

var canvasCenter = canvas.getCenter();

// Add background and position it in the center of canvas
var background_rec = new fabric.Rect({
    fill: 'lightblue',
    angle: 0,
    hasControls: false,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    lockMovementX: true,
    lockMovementY: true,
    selectable: false,
    left: canvasCenter["left"],
    top: canvasCenter["top"],
    width: 400,
    height: 225
});
canvas.add(background_rec);

// Position where the background starts
var zero_position_left = canvasCenter["left"] - background_rec.width/2;
var zero_position_top =  canvasCenter["top"] - background_rec.height/2;

var title_input = new fabric.IText('Custom Text', {
     fontFamily: 'arial black',
     fontStyle: 'normal',
     fontSize: $j('#configurator-fontsize').val(),
                    fill: 'red',
     hasControls: false,
     lockMovementX: false,
     lockMovementY: false,
     centerTransform: false,
     left: zero_position_left + 40,
     top: zero_position_top - 0.95*$j("#configurator-fontsize").val(),
     width: 300,
     height: 90
});
canvas.add(title_input);
canvas.sendToBack(title_input);


// Add input field for content1
var content1_input = new fabric.IText('Custom Content', {
     fontFamily: 'arial black',
     fontStyle: 'normal',
     fontSize: $j('#configurator-fontsize').val(),
                    fill: 'red',
     stroke: '#999',
     hasControls: false,
     lockMovementX: true,
     lockMovementY: true,
     left: zero_position_left + 70,
     top: zero_position_top + 60,
     width: 300,
     height: 80
});
canvas.add(content1_input);

canvas.renderAll();


// Canvas actions
// Change text-align
$j("#configurator-align").change(function() {
    // Get active element
    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    
    if(activeObject && activeObject.get('type') === 'i-text') {
        activeObject.set({textAlign: $j("#configurator-align").val()});
        canvas.renderAll();
    } else console.log('No Text Object selected.');
});

// Change font-size
$j("#configurator-fontsize").change(function() {
    // Get active element
    var activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    
    if(activeObject && activeObject.get('type') === 'i-text') {
        if(activeObject == title_input) {
            activeObject.set({fontSize: $j("#configurator-fontsize").val(), top: (zero_position_top - 0.90*$j("#configurator-fontsize").val() )});
        } else {
            activeObject.set({fontSize: $j("#configurator-fontsize").val()});
        }
        canvas.renderAll();
    } else console.log('No Text Object selected.');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="controls">
     <h3>Controls:</h3>

    <p>
        <label>Align:</label>
        <br />
        <select id="configurator-align">
            <option value="left">left</option>
            <option value="center">center</option>
            <option value="right">right</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Font-size:</label>
        <br />
        <select id="configurator-fontsize">
            <!-- Values are given as pixels -->
            <!-- Approximate Conversion from Points to Pixels used -->
            <option value="16">12pt</option>
            <option value="19">14pt</option>
            <option value="22">16pt</option>
            <option value="24">18pt</option>
            <option value="26">20pt</option>
            <option value="29">22pt</option>
            <option value="32">24pt</option>
            <option value="35">26pt</option>
            <option value="37">28pt</option>
            <option value="40">30pt</option>
            <option value="45">34pt</option>
            <option value="48">36pt</option>
        </select>            
</div>

<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Innodel thank you for your reply. Unfortunately I cannot accept this answer. Even if this solves the problem on Android, is this solution not acceptable because it changes the nature of the input fields. The input fields must remain fix in position. Setting lockMovementX and lockMovementY to false enables the user to reposition them.

Comment: I have tested your solution on my Samsung Galaxy S5 and the text fields are not editable. So setting lockMovementX and lockMovementY to false, does not solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `event.keyCode` values of most keys in Android are 0, fabric will add nothing into the IText's content.

There is no direct solution for this problem; rather, whenever an iText is selected, you can focus on an outer input field and change value of your IText field based on that input field. Here is my sample [jsjiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tblaziken/gpkk1y1d/1/). The input field can be set hidden to make Fabric IText behavior look more natural.

Again, this is a problem of Android, so any Javascript library that read key's value based on `event.keyCode`, `event.charCode` or `event.which` will likely to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I recently faced the same problem, the issue is due to event key code in mobile devices.

The workaround is instead of getting char from each keypress, bind an event-handler to input on hidden text object and sync itext object text.
In fabricjs instead of `fabric.util.addListener(this.hiddenTextarea, 'keypress', this.onKeyPress.bind(this));` use `fabric.util.addListener(this.hiddenTextarea, "input", this.thisOnInputText.bind(this))`

and in eventhandler thisOnInputText do something like this :

```
this.text = this.hiddenTextarea.value
```

just like _updateTextarea function.

> this is for fabricjs version: "1.5.0"